# Cypher Neo4J - CASE Expression with MERGE

Tags: merge, neo4j, logic, case, cypher

I'm trying to implement the logic in Cypher where, based on a particular condition (`CASE` Statement), I would create some nodes and relationships;  the code is as below

```
MATCH (g:Game)-[:PLAYER]->(u:User)-[r1:AT]->(b1:Block)-[:NEXT]->(b2:Block) 
WHERE g.game_id='G222' and u.email_id = 'xyz@example.com' and b1.block_id='16' 
SET r1.status='Skipped', r1.enddate=20141225
WITH u, b2,b1, g, r1
SET b1.test = CASE b2.fork 
WHEN 'y' THEN
     MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2     {fork:'fail'}) RETURN 1
ELSE 
     MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2)   RETURN 2
END
WITH u, g
MATCH (u)-[:TIME]->(h:Time)<-[:TIME]-(g)
SET h.after = 0
SET h.before = h.before + 1
```

In this query there is a `merge` statement within the `WHEN 'y' THEN`, this query throws an error:

> Invalid input ']': expected whitespace or a relationship pattern (line 7, column 82)
>       "MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2 {fork:'fail'}) RETURN 1"

Basically I'm trying to create a relationship based on a property i.e. a `MERGE` within a `CASE` statement, I tried different ways to get this working like doing a return so that case when returns some value etc. but nothing worked so far.

What could be the issue with this query?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To do conditional write operations you need to use the `FOREACH` trick. Using `CASE` you either return a one element array or a empty one. `FOREACH` iterates over the `CASE` expression and therefore conditionally executes the action. If you want an `ELSE` part as well you need to have a another `FOREACH` using the inverse condition in the `CASE`. As an example, instead of

```
WHEN 'y' THEN
   MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2     {fork:'fail'}) RETURN 1
ELSE 
    MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2)   RETURN 2
END
```

use

```
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN 'y' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
    MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2 {fork:'fail'})
)
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN NOT 'y' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
    MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2)
)
```

See also [Mark's blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/08/22/neo4j-load-csv-handling-empty-columns/) on this.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, yes you are correct, it seems we need to use FOREACH, I also referred to one of your earlier posts in StackOverflow, the logic finally is like this                           WITH u, b2,b1, g, r1, CASE  WHEN (b1.fork='y' and b2.fork='success') or (b1.fork='n') or (b1.fork='success') THEN ['ok'] ELSE [] END as array1
FOREACH (el1 in array1 | MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:99999999, status:'InProgress'}]->(b2))

Comment: Nice trick, but can you explain what is the meaning of `THEN [1] ELSE []`, and what is `ignoreMe` *(sorry, I couldn't ignore you)*?

Comment: No update in Cypher allowing us to forget about this hack yet? I would really like to read that this response is outdated now in 2018.

Comment: @HerrIvan is this still the only way to conditionally merge?

Comment: @bigmadwolf: Yep. That was my question one year ago. But no answer since then... Maybe Stefan Armbruster knows better.

Comment: this works but it is a horrible hack for such a common use case "if I can find this node, join it to this other node"

Answer (score 4):

The APOC plugin supports [Conditional Cypher Execution](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/conditionals/), which now allows us to avoid the `FOREACH` workaround.

For example, you can do this:

```
MATCH (g:Game)-[:PLAYER]->(u:User)-[r1:AT]->(b1:Block)-[:NEXT]->(b2:Block) 
WHERE g.game_id='G222' AND u.email_id = 'xyz@example.com' AND b1.block_id='16' 
SET r1.status='Skipped', r1.enddate=20141225
WITH u, b2, g
CALL apoc.do.when(
  b2.fork = 'y',
  "MERGE (u)-[:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2     {fork:'fail'})",
  "MERGE (u)-[:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:'99999999', status:'InProgress'}]->(b2)",
  {u: u, b2: b2}) YIELD value
WITH u, g
MATCH (u)-[:TIME]->(h:Time)<-[:TIME]-(g)
SET h.after = 0
SET h.before = h.before + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue as below

```
WITH u, b2,b1, g, r1, CASE  WHEN (b1.fork='y' and b2.fork='success') or (b1.fork='n') or   (b1.fork='success') THEN ['ok'] ELSE [] END as array1
FOREACH (el1 in array1 | MERGE (u)-[r2:STAGE {startdate:20141225, enddate:99999999, status:'InProgress'}]->(b2))
```

i.e. used CASE WHEN to create a dummy array that in a way has dummy elements matching the count of matches and then use FOREACH to iterate through the result.

Again, thanks Stefan for the idea...

Deepesh

Comment: it would be neater if you don't put your long business logic inside CQL.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer does help me, I found the syntax very hard to understand. So that's why I wrote my own answer. Here I read a *tsv* file and generate multiple types of edges.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data.tsv' AS r FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
WITH r.movie_id as movie_id, r.person_id as person_id, r.category as category
MATCH (p:Person {person_id:person_id})
MATCH (m:Movie {movie_id:movie_id})
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN category='actress' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (p)-[:ACTRESS {}]->(m)
)
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN category='director' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (p)-[:DIRECTOR {}]->(m)
)    
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN category='cinematographer' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (p)-[:CINEMATOGRAPHER {}]->(m)
)
FOREACH (_ IN CASE WHEN category='actor' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (p)-[:ACTOR {}]->(m)
)
```

Here `_` is some variable which is simply not used anywhere but a necessity for the syntax of cypher