# Neo4j-Multiple match statement in cypher query with if else conditon

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have to search certain nodes like eq.page whether or not they have relation or not with some other node..like tags.

> ```
>  If they are connected to tag nodes then search for the search string in page name and the tag names 
>
> Else search for the search string in page name only
> ```

```
MATCH ...//nodes of certain type    
WHERE    
    if r is null'
      ...//Match query without relation for searching
    else 
      ...//Match query without relation for searching

Return ...

MATCH (n:page)<-[r:pagetag]-(tag)
if  r is null 
then n.title CONTAINS 'java'or tag.name IN ["java"] 
return distinct n.name
else  n.title CONTAINS 'java'return distinct n.name
  END
```

This query is giving error. May be syntax problem. But I want to search for  like this only for the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally acheieved what I wanted. Thanks all. OPTIONAL Match worked great for me.

```
MATCH (s:page)
WITH s
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)<-[r:pagetag]-(tag)
WITH s,r,tag
Where s.pagename contains 'juniors'or tag.name contains 'math'
return distinct s.pagename
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that just basic conditionals?

```
MATCH (n:page)<-[r:pagetag]-(tag)
WITH n,r,tag
WHERE r IS NULL AND (n.title CONTAINS 'java' or tag.name IN ["java"])
OR NOT r is NULL AND (n.title CONTAINS 'java')
return distinct n.name
```

Comment: Sir its not still working for me. As if the page node and tag node don't have relation then the particular page node doesn't get searched by this query. I m sorry but need your guidance.Till the time I am working on it. thank you

Comment: Actually Sir I am using neo4j ver 2.3.2 where the null check and the where not clauses were not working. Optional Match saved me. THanku so much. I have posted the correct query

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use if else in Neo4j you have to use case, or foreach to simulate  if .

Comment: Do cases can have the queries like i want to make the condition for if-else

Comment: yes see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576427/cypher-neo4j-case-expression-with-merge

Comment: please read my question again. May be I am unable to make you understand but that question didn't helped me.