# Issue in Cypher query using if if and merge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In given cypher query it showing error. Please let me know what is wrong in below Cypher query:

```
MATCH (pcp:PCP)-[]->(mt:MONEYTRANSFER{MTCN:'1618087665684829'}) return 
CASE WHEN  EXISTS( (pcp)-[:SENT_BY]-(mt{MTCN:'1618087665684829'}) ) 
THEN null ELSE MERGE (pcp:PCP)-[]->(mt:MONEYTRANSFER{MTCN:'1618087665684829'})
END
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try going through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576427/cypher-neo4j-case-expression-with-merge) on stackoverflow. It gives the example of using CASES with MERGE

there's a work around for your query:

```
MATCH (pcp:PCP)-[r]->(mt:MONEYTRANSFER{MTCN:'1618087665684829'})
WITH pcp,r,mt, CASE WHEN (type(r) = 'SENT_BY') THEN [] ELSE ['create'] 
END as array1
FOREACH (el1 in array1 | CREATE (pcp)-[:SENT_BY]->(mt))
return pcp,mt,r
```

Edit: You cannot create a realtionship without specifying the label/type for it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it should be comment

Comment: @GovindSingh i was editing my answer. And as you can see i don't have the commenting privilege yet