# CQL Syntax exception

Tags: neo4j, cypher

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input ')': expected
>   whitespace or a relationship pattern (line 66, column 100 (offset:
>   1898)) "CREATE (z:Subscription{ subscriptionId: subs.subscriptionId,
>   startDate: subs.startDate, endDate:''})<-[r:ASSOCIATION]-(y:Person
>   {nationalIdentityNumber: subs.nationalIdentityNumber, name: subs.name,
>   surname: subs.surname, fathername: subs.fathername , nationality:
>   subs.nationality, passportNo: subs.passportNo, birthdate:
>   subs.birthdate})"

I want to create/merge nodes and relation that types are Person, Subscription and Line

If I had same subscription I should check to startDate, If new data's start date greater then old data; I sould create new Subscription and also change old subscription's end date.

```
UNWIND  [{
msisdn:'99658321564',
name:'Lady',
surname:'Camble',
fatherName:'Aeron',
nationality:'EN',
passportNo:'PN-1234224',
birthDate:'12-05-1979',
nationalIdentityNumber:'112124224',
subscriptionId:'2009201999658321564',
startDate:'20-09-2019 12:00:12'
},{msisdn:'99658363275',
name:'John',
surname:'Mckeen',
fatherName:'Frank',
nationality:'EN',
passportNo:'PN-126587',
birthDate:'15-08-1998',
nationalIdentityNumber:'2548746542',
subscriptionId:'1506201999658363275',
startDate:'15-06-2019 13:00:12'}
{
msisdn:'99658321564',
name:'Lady',
surname:'Camble',
fatherName:'Aeron',
nationality:'EN',
passportNo:'PN-1234224',
birthDate:'12-05-1979',
nationalIdentityNumber:'112124224',
subscriptionId:'2009201999658321564',
startDate:'31-11-2019 12:00:12'
}
] as subs
MERGE (y:Person {nationalIdentityNumber: subs.nationalIdentityNumber, name:         subs.name, surname: subs.surname, fathername: subs.fathername , nationality: subs.nationality, passportNo: subs.passportNo, birthdate: subs.birthdate  })
MERGE (t:Subscription{subscriptionId:subs.subscriptionId })
MERGE (y)-[rel:ASSOCIATION]-(t)
ON MATCH SET
t.endDate = (case when t.startDate <subs.startDate then subs.startDate else '' 
end) 
MATCH (t:Subscription) where t.subscriprionId=subs.subscriprionId and
(CASE
WHEN  t.endDate=subs.startDate then 
CREATE (z:Subscription{ subscriptionId: subs.subscriptionId, startDate: subs.startDate, endDate:''})-[r:ASSOCIATION]-(y:Person {nationalIdentityNumber: subs.nationalIdentityNumber, name: subs.name, surname: subs.surname, fathername: subs.fathername , nationality: subs.nationality, passportNo: subs.passportNo, birthdate: subs.birthdate})
END)
 RETURN y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UNWIND[...] as subs
MERGE (y:Person {nationalIdentityNumber: subs.nationalIdentityNumber, name: subs.name, surname: subs.surname, fatherName: subs.fatherName , nationality: subs.nationality, passportNo: subs.passportNo, birthDate: subs.birthDate  })
MERGE (t:Subscription{subscriptionId:subs.subscriptionId,startDate:subs.startDate,endDate:''})
MERGE (y)-[rel:ASSOCIATION]-(t)
MERGE(x:Subscription{subscriptionId:subs.subscriptionId, endDate:''})
SET
x.endDate = (case when x.startDate < subs.startDate then subs.startDate else null end);
```

CQL should like this. Thanks my co-worker.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to have conditional Cypher clauses through a CASE statement, and that won't work. You can't do a nested CREATE (or any other Cypher clause) in a CASE.

You can however use a [trick with FOREACH and CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27578798/92359) to mimic an `if` conditional. That should work in your case, as you want to only execute a CREATE under certain conditions (though since you already matched to the `y` node for the person, just reuse `(y)` in that CREATE instead of trying to define the entire node again from labels and properties, that won't work properly).

If you need more advanced conditional logic, that's available via [conditional procs in APOC Procedures](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/cypher-execution/conditionals/)